# VS2008 assembly load problem

Tags: visual-studio-2008

I have .NET solution in VS2008. In my solution there are 20 projects. In Debug configuration everything is OK. But in Release configuration there is problem with loading one specific assembly(class library from my projects).

> Could not load file or assembly 'Solution.Project, Version=1.0.3929.32377, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.

My system is Windows 7 prof. 64bit. I checked directory and file(.dll) is OK. On other computers it`s OK.
I checked out working copy to another directory and same problem.

Where can be problem please?

Comment: no one? please help i don`t know how resolve it :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try comparing the project properties for Debug and Release, and doing the same for one of the projects that does work correctly in both Debug/Release modes? You probably have, but I can't shake the feeling something about your projects dependencies has been configured incorrectly in Release mode.

Comment: Finally I resolve the issue. Problem was in configurations as you suggest(i didn`t noticed one setting). I have x64 system, and all project has AnyCPU config, but one project loads 3th party library compiled as x86.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you use process monitor from msft.  This will show you what dll and where it is being loaded from.  Maybe there is a dependany dll that us causing this issue.